# Why value of x is 28 in the given 'C' code snippet?

Tags: c, logic

```
char str1[] = "dills";
char str2[20] ="Hello";
char str3[] = "daffo";
int x;
x = strcmp("daffodills",strcat(str3, strcpy(str1, str2)));
```

I think -- strcpy(str1, str2)) makes str1= “Hello”.
 Hence, strcat(str3, strcpy(str1, str2))= strcat(str3,”Hello”)= daffoHello. Finally, strcmp(“daffodills”, “daffoHello”)=1 as the ASCII value of first unmatched character (d) is greater than second (H).

But , compiler value of x is 28 in the output.

Comment: Even if it wasn't for the undefined behavior, `strcmp` is only guaranteed to return some value which can be positive, negative, or zero. It doesn't have to be specifically 1.

Comment: `'d' - 'H'` in ASCII gives `100 - 72`, which is `28`. But that's implementation defined, so don't rely on it.

Comment: Where did you get the information that `strcmp` should return `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's undefined behavior. `char str3[] = "daffo";` makes the array just big enough to hold `"dills"` and the following null terminator. Then you do this:

```
strcat(str3, strcpy(str1, str2)));
```

Which appends another string to that, which causes it to overflow. We could speculate why `x` is `28`, but there's no point as there's no guarantee on its value. It could be anything else, or the program could crash before it outputs the result (for me, there's a stack corruption, crashing the program. This means that a memory location that is important for the program's control flow to work, such as a stack pointer, got mangled by the undefined behavior that the `strcat` causes).

---

Besides, [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) gives return values defined as being `0`, something positive or something negative. That's the only guarantee, I've seen implementations where it could return something like `28` and implementations where it will always return `0`, `1` or `-1`. So even if the program is well-defined the question "why does it return `28`" couldn't be answered without more information on the `strcmp` implementation used.

Comment: You said the program could crash as ther's stack corruption , what do you mean by stack corruption?

Comment: @SuklavGhosh good question! I added a short explanation on that which OP can hopefully understand. Strictly speaking there's not even a guarantee that stack corruption may happen at all because the standard doesn't even mandate a stack, so theoretically someone could make a crazy implementation of C that works without a stack.

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because the ASCII values are different for uppercase and lowercase letters.
ASCII value of uppercase H is 72 and of lowercase d is 100
100-72 = 28
Your compiler is returning the ASCII value difference.
 If you want to ignore cases, use `stricmp()`. 
If you use this, you will get 4.